# How to add text on hover in a video element and also adding a hover overlay

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

The tiles [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgZvN.png) are video elements, when I click them a video is being played. I have added a hover pop out function with custom CSS in the tiles. I want to add a text and description on hover and also I want to add an overlay when the tiles are hoverd. Is this possible? I am using elementor and wordpress.

Comment: You can use javascript. You can bind an eventlistener to each video and when hovered on any of them you can display text whatever way you want.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Would you mind editing the question so that it includes screenshots and code you've worked on so far?

Comment: thanks for replying @ArunBohra, I am really new to this kind of stuff. I dont even know how to add javascript to my elementor elements. Could you kindly tell me more on how to do this, would mean a lot really :)

Comment: @JongwooLee thanks for your suggestion, I have edited the post as you have said.

Comment: @MohammadShifat, here, take a look at elementor docs where they tell you how you can add custom JS to elementor editor. https://essential-addons.com/elementor/docs/custom-js/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the **EA Custom JS** extension is activated. Head over to your WordPress Dashboard and navigate to Essential **Addons→ Extensions**. Look for the ‘**Custom JS**’ extension and click to activate it. Afterward, click ‘Save Settings’ to save your changes.

To configure the EA Custom JS extension, open your Elementor page from your WordPress Dashboard. Afterward, click on ‘Page Settings’ which you can find at the bottom of the Elementor Editor, and head over to the ‘Advanced’ tab.

You will then be able to see the ‘EA Custom JS’ along with an input field to add your custom JavaScript snippet. Afterward, simply just insert your JavaScript code snippet inside this input field under ‘EA Custom JS’ section to add extra customization.

Here I would suggest to use a simple setTimeout function for 10ms and write whole javascript inside it.

Comment: okay I did that, one last thing, could you kindly provide me the code for showing the text on hover and also tell me how to add it to my video elements? I am totally new to this stuff and I looked on the internet but I couldnt find anything :)

Comment: I can't write that long code but if you are new then you should prefer learning these which will help get this particular job done. Positioning in css , using js to select elements, adding eventlisteners in javascript like mouseover, hover state in css and you can get all of these on the internet. I think it would be enough to solve your problem. If not then ask and I will write the code as well.

Comment: thanks for your help man